# What is the encoding of this data? Is it corrupted?

Tags: encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I have this file which store some strings data for i18n. Here is the raw data in HEX:

```
70617573652E70726F636573732E6D73
673D20496D706F737369626C65206427
696E746572726F6D707265206C652070
726F6365737375732E204C6520737461
74757420646F697420EFBFBD74726520
27456E20636F7572732064276578EFBF
BD637574696F6E272E0D0A
```

in Base64

```
cGF1c2UucHJvY2Vzcy5tc2c9IEltcG9zc2libGUgZCdpbnRlcnJvbXByZSBsZSBwcm9jZXNzdXMuIExlIHN0YXR1dCBkb2l0IO+/vXRyZSAnRW4gY291cnMgZCdleO+/vWN1dGlvbicuDQo=
```

If I try to decode in UTF-8 using [this tool](https://string-functions.com/hex-string.aspx) i get:

```
pause.process.msg= Impossible d'interrompre le processus. Le statut doit ï¿½tre 'En cours d'exï¿½cution'.
```

note that `0D0A` is simple ASCII `\r\n`

I am expecting:

```
pause.process.msg= Impossible d'interrompre le processus. Le statut doit être 'En cours d'exécution'.
```

I am french and i can state that both `é` and `ê` char are encoded to `EFBFBD` in this data.

Then my 'simple' question is what is this encoding?

Note that UTF8 encodes `é` to `C3A9`, Latin-1 `E9`.

Comment: this tool does not decode UTF-8

Comment: `note that 0D0A is simple ASCII \r\n` the issue here is probably Windows EOL (end of line) conversion gone wrong. In Windows, EOL is `\r\n` but it's different on other platforms, so sometimes bytes get added or removed depending on the exact conversion.

Comment: Why have you tagged `c` and `python` here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fixing mojibakes in UTF-8 text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48430825/fixing-mojibakes-in-utf-8-text)

Comment: After more research, it looks like VScode tried to open the file which was encoded using windows-1252 codepage, in utf-8 (default in the settings). Then for obscure reason _silently_ changed, what looked for him bad utf-8 encoding to U+FFFD.
I'm still not sure if VScode actually change the file on the disk or if it's just a display issue. That's another question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61470359/is-there-a-way-to-make-vs-code-not-replace-unknown-text-characters

Comment: "If I try to decode in UTF-8 using this tool" - in your own words, **why do you expect** that the tool does **anything related to** UTF-8? I don't see the term UTF-8 anywhere on that page. Also, *what is supposed to be the point* of using an online "hex to text converter tool" on the "raw data in HEX" that you showed us - presumably by hex-dumping the file that was not already hex?

Comment: If you have a file that you believe represents text in UTF-8 encoding, then the way to test that hypothesis - i.e., to "try to decode in UTF-8" - is to *open and read that file in your code, as text, in a way appropriate to those assumptions*. For example, `with open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as f: text = f.read()` in Python. Alternately, you could try *opening the file in a text editor, explicitly telling it the file encoding, with an editor that allows you to do so*. If you had tried either of those things, you would have seen the `�` in the output which you could have asked about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text was decoded incorrectly in the past then encoded as UTF-8 again.

```py
import unicodedata as ud

s = bytes.fromhex('''\
70617573652E70726F636573732E6D73
673D20496D706F737369626C65206427
696E746572726F6D707265206C652070
726F6365737375732E204C6520737461
74757420646F697420EFBFBD74726520
27456E20636F7572732064276578EFBF
BD637574696F6E272E0D0A''').decode('utf8')

print('Original:      ', s)
print('Escapes:      ', ascii(s))
print('character name:', ud.name('\ufffd'))
print()

# How this could happen
s = "pause.process.msg= Impossible d'interrompre le processus. Le statut doit être 'En cours d'exécution'.\r\n"
print('Correct:   ', s)
s2 = s.encode('latin1').decode('utf8', errors='replace') # encoded, then decoded incorrectly
print('Bad decode:', s2)
print('Escapes:  ', ascii(s2))
```

Output:

```
Original:       pause.process.msg= Impossible d'interrompre le processus. Le statut doit �tre 'En cours d'ex�cution'.

Escapes:       "pause.process.msg= Impossible d'interrompre le processus. Le statut doit \ufffdtre 'En cours d'ex\ufffdcution'.\r\n"
character name: REPLACEMENT CHARACTER

Correct:    pause.process.msg= Impossible d'interrompre le processus. Le statut doit être 'En cours d'exécution'.

Bad decode: pause.process.msg= Impossible d'interrompre le processus. Le statut doit �tre 'En cours d'ex�cution'.

Escapes:   "pause.process.msg= Impossible d'interrompre le processus. Le statut doit \ufffdtre 'En cours d'ex\ufffdcution'.\r\n"
```

Answer (score 3):

1. The tool you used does not decode UTF-8 but some other encoding (probably Latin-1 or Windows-1252 etc.)
2. EFBFBD is the UTF-8 code for U+FFFD
3. U+FFFD is the standard "replacement character" � which means an unknown or unencodable character.

So the text went through some tool that could not handle é and changed it to � or possibly some corrupted text. Then the � was encoded as UTF-8.